# Using a conditional if statement in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a linq query that uses an if statement.

In the code below I'm searching for matches of

n.SAU_ID = sau.SAUID where

ReportingPeriod column contains "Oct1" then
 FiscalYear - aprYearDiff = sau.SAUYearCode.

Else

FiscalYear - octYearDiff = sau.SAUYearCode.

My code is only giving matches for the SAUID and "Oct1".

What code is needed to implement theese statements?

```
    int FiscalYear = 2014;       

    List<String> addtowns = new List<string>();

    List<Stage_Reorg> reorg = _entities.Stage_Reorg.ToList();

    int aprYearDiff = 2;
    int octYearDiff = 1;

    foreach (var sau in reorg)
    {
        addtowns.AddRange(_entities.Stage_EPSSubsidySADCSDTown
        .Where(n => n.SAU_ID == sau.SAUID 
            && (n.ReportingPeriod == "Oct1" 
            ? (FiscalYear - aprYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode 
            : (FiscalYear - octYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode))
        .Select(n =>  n.TownCode ));
    }
```

Comment: you can fix the syntax but I don't think it will work with EF anyway.

Comment: `.where( a => { /*some code */  return /*some bool value*/} )`

Comment: @EugenePodskal That was actually easier to read before the edit.

Comment: @DCShannon Well, I do not say that I've made some really good formatting there. Just I am a firm believer in fair use of tabs and abundant use of parentheses to make code more readable (at least for me). Overall it is a matter of taste and personal preferences, so feel free to rollback it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea anyway. Transform the condition to

```
(n.ReportingPeriod == "Oct1" && (FiscalYear - aprYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode)  
|| (n.ReportingPeriod != "Oct1" && (FiscalYear - octYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode)
```

Comment: Could elaborate on why it's a bad idea, but upvoted anyway, as this should work better and is logically equivalent.

Comment: Because declarative code is better than imperative code and this one is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way but this probably won't work with EF. You will need to load all records into memory then perform the filtering:

```
addtowns.AddRange(_entities.Stage_EPSSubsidySADCSDTown
    .Where(n => { 
                   bool b = n.ReportingPeriod == "Oct1" 
                           ? (FiscalYear - aprYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode 
                           : (FiscalYear - octYearDiff) == sau.SAUYearCode);
                  return b && n.SAU_ID == sau.SAUID;
                 }).Select(n =>  n.TownCode ))
```

Comment: I take to long to type. but I agree completely